# Popup using ajax in spring mvc

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller, popup

I am developing spring mvc application with two html pages. student.html and details.html. In student.html I have "studentId" and "view" button.when user clicks on view button, request goes to controller, fetch student details from DB and display in popup using details.html page with student.html as main page at background. The issue is when I click on view button control goes to details page. It was not coming as popup. Please guide how to achieve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.